ruby 3.1: Using &method(:name) to simplify code fails inexplicably
ruby 3.1.2
kubuntu 22.04
The method to extract the base domain name (excluding sub-domain) from a URI:
def host_name(a)
  URI(a).host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')
end

Use:
uri_array = ['https://www.example.org', 'http://www.example.net/posts?a=1', 'www.example.com']
uri_array.map!(&method(:host_name))

expected output: =>
['example.org', 'example.net', 'example.com']

instead produces:
(irb):14:in `host_name': undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

with the resultant array modified like so:
[
    [0] "example.org",
    [1] "example.net",
    [2] "www.example.com"
]

Why it should fail on the 3rd element of the array.

If a loop fails for a specific element, it's most likely not the loop but that specific element.

IMO map!(&method(:host_name)) is not simplifying and map! { |u| host_name(u) } is more readable

& in this context is known as the safe navigation operator.

@max & is shorthand to_proc in this context

@engineersmnky you're absolutely right. oops

The problem here is not the use of &method, but with the uri being passed to URI. When the uri to be parsed doesn't contain a scheme (like http, https, etc), URI will not be able to extract the host property:
irb(main):001> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002> uri = URI('www.example.com')
=> #<URI::Generic www.example.com>
irb(main):003> uri.host
=> nil
irb(main):004> uri.path
=> "www.example.com"
irb(main):005> uri.host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')
(irb):5:in `<main>': undefined method `sub' for nil (NoMethodError)

uri.host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')
        ^^^^
        from <internal:kernel>:187:in `loop'
        from /Users/jason/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/gems/irb-1.12.0/exe/irb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/jason/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/bin/irb:25:in `load'
        from /Users/jason/.gem/ruby/3.3.0/bin/irb:25:in `<main>'
irb(main):006>

However, you can use the addressable gem, and particularly Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse for this situation instead.

Converts an input to a URI. The input does not have to be a valid URI — the method will use heuristics to guess what URI was intended. This is not standards-compliant, merely user-friendly.

irb(main):001> require 'addressable'
=> true
irb(main):002> uri = Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse('www.example.com')
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x2ee0 URI:http://www.example.com>
irb(main):003> uri.host
=> "www.example.com"
irb(main):004>


The reason why the third URI doesn't work is because it is not a URI. A URI must include a scheme (see Section 3 Syntax Components of RFC 3986 – Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax).
A URI would look like one of these examples:

http://www.example.com
ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt
ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one
mailto:John.Doe@example.com
news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix
tel:+1-816-555-1212
telnet://192.0.2.16:80/
urn:oasis:names:specification:docbook:dtd:xml:4.1.2

